# Cannot play sound in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios

I cannot play sound in iOS Safari. I've looked into similar issues on StackOverflow, most suggested that it could only work with user interactions(onclick, ontouchstart, etc.). But my code doesn't work even if the playing is initiated by `onclick`. Here is my code.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <button onclick="playSound()">Play Sound</button>
  <script>
    function playSound() {
      var audio = new Audio("source.wav");
      audio.play();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works in desktop browsers but failed in iOS Safari. Why? I'm using iOS 12.0.1

Comment: Maybe it's the wav file itself. Did you try different sounds? Maybe a .mp3?

Comment: @obscure Thanks, it's a good point. I tried a mp3 file just now and it worked! Now I need to figure out how to make wav files work.

Answer (score 0):

As @obscure suggested in the comment, iOS Safari doesn't work with wav files by default. I converted all the wav files to mp3 and it works now.